# Plotting by groupby and mean

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset that contains names, Name of Movie, and Score

I am new to python, therefore I don't understand how I am supposed to make a horizontal bar chart that shows me the average score of each movie.

I started like:

> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> import pandas as pd
>
> plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
>
> df = pd.read_csv('movies.csv', sep=';')
>
> print(df.shape)
>
> print(df.head())
>
> mean = df.groupby(['Name of Movie']).mean()
>
> labels = mean.index.values
>
> values = mean['Score'].values

I am unsure how to continue to display such chart

Comment: `df.groupby(['Name of Movie']).Score.mean().plot(kind='barh')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby('Name of Movie').Score.mean().plot(kind='barh')
```